# OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier with angular4

Tags: angular, leaflet

I am trying to use OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier with leaflet in my angular 4 app.
The module works fine in plain js and with angular 1.

But when i try to use it with angular 4, it gives me the error

```
ERROR ReferenceError: OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is not defined
```

It was solved when I installed the overlapping-marker-spiderfier

```
npm i overlapping-marker-spiderfier
```

But then it gave an another error that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

What should I do to get it working

Comment: I know this is very old, but probably the problem was you were using the `Google Maps` version of the library, not the `Leaflet` version of the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using the [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier javascript file](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/bin/oms.min.js) for leaflet.You have to change the file in a way similar to the npm version of OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier for google map.

Add

```
this['OverlappingMarkerSpiderfierLeafLet'] = (function() {
  if (this['L'] == null) {
    return;
}
```

at the beginning and export the module as

```
module.exports = this['OverlappingMarkerSpiderfierLeafLet'];
```

Then this can be used by importing the module and using it as same as you do in html

Comment: How does the final javascript file looks like then?

Answer (score 0):

First I assume that you have script tag with your google maps api included into index.html.

Do you have @types/googlemaps installed? If not try to install it with

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

and then include folowing import into your component

```
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
```

I hope this solves your problem. If not then try to declare this in your component

```
declare var google: any;
@Component({
    ...
})
```

Comment: I had already added the types and the variable. The errors were thrown from the osm.js file in the node_modules folder